# Flutter setState isn't triggered in Android studio

Tags: flutter, setstate

I'm absolutely new to programming and Flutter as well, so sorry for my silly question but I can't find in Google the reason why when I'm starting to type setState in Android studio it isn't popped up (from code helper) and I'm forced to remember the right spelling for this method.

Hope you can help me because I really can't understand how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

```
class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  late Gender selectedGender;
  int height = 180;
  int weight = 60;
  int age = 19;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableCard(
                    onPress: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == Gender.male
                        ? kActiveCardColour
                        : kInactiveCardColour,
                    cardChild: IconContent(
                      icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                      label: 'MALE',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Is it only set state? Or all suggestions are missing? If only set state maybe you are trying to write it in a stateless widget

Comment: @KaushikChandru
I've added some code - I'm writing setState inside the stateful widget. As for the other suggestions everything is absolutely OK. Why it is so I can't understand

Answer (score 0):

```
label: selectedGender == Gender.male?'MALE':"FEMALE",
```

You added male directly. Please make it display based on selectedGender.

Comment: Still nothing new. No any suggestions for setState

Comment: If you are using android studio. Click on file -> invalidate cache. Then on the pop up click on invalidate and restart

Comment: Nothing changed. Maybe some glitches in Flutter 3.0

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me, but apparently it is a change in the version of Android Studio (if you are working with Android Studio), personally I have not wanted to rollback because it is a lot of work, but in a few weeks it has not been corrected by means of some update or something like that I think it will be time to do it

By the way, neither setState nor initState nor several other methods work

My current version of Android Studio is as follows

[image]

Comment: In fact, I already did the downgrade and now everything works correctly.
I would recommend using the version.

Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 2

You can find it in this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input I'll definitely try to downgrade. Hope they fix it in nearest time